# XMLHttpRequest cannot load "THIS URL" Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

Im getting this error when trying to POST and XML from my company website to FRESHDESK API

here is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = 
  '<helpdesk_ticket>' +
    '<description>This is a test</description>' +
    '<email>sample@example.com</email>' + 
  '</helpdesk_ticket>'
$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://onehouse.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets.xml',
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: data,
    dataType: "text",
    username: 'MY API CODE',
    password: 'X',

    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
  });
```

the full error is

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://onehouse.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets.xml. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. contacts?oid=00DU0000000I430&retURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ironridge.com&email=ma…utes%5D%5Bdescription_html%5D=safsadfsdaf&00NU0000002xpYP=&submit=Submit:1
```

Does anyone have any solutions to this........it does not post the data to the FRESHDESK WEBSITE and i've been banging my heads for days now

Comment: setting `$.support.cors` to true and `crossDomain: true` do nothing to help your cause.

Comment: Do you own/control onehouse.freshdesk.com? if not, there isn't much you can do aside from instead having your server get the data.

Answer (score 1):

It says it right there in the error.

You **cannot** do any AJAX requests (aside from `jsonp`) to a different domain due to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Comment: thank you for telling me the error but i was really looking for a solution though

Comment: @RickyAhn There is **no** solution. It is a browser restriction.

Comment: You need to read up on CORS and understand the basics of it rather than ask for shake and bake solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a CORS feature (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Even though you set `crossDomain` to `true` in your request, the server that you post to has to support CORS for this to work. Namely, the server has to respond with specific HTTP headers for the browser to allow this request.